# When an object hangs from a Rigid rod is the force of the weight located in the center of the sign?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, statics

[image]

From the rope that supports the sign (assuming the mass is distributed evenly).

If the length of the sign is, $L$ can I model it so that the weight is concentrated at $\frac{L}{2}$ Therefore, the force of the whole sign would be located on the pole at $80+\frac{L}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weight of your sign is actually supported by the two tiny threads that connect it to the rod.

The weight of the sign is distributed among these two threads, the amount of weight at each one will depend on the distribution of mass of the sign. Assuming that your sign is homogeneous and that the threads are positioned simmetrically, they both will support the same weight.

How these two forces affect the rod depends on the rest of the system. For example, if you hold the rod just from the middle of the two threads, then the sign will be horizontal. But if you hold the rod from the point where the left thread is attached, the sign will rotate to the right.

In your particular problem, I think that the rod works as a lever, the hinge being at the wall. If this is the case, then it is equivalent to the sign being hung from the middle point between the two threads. This is because the torque at the hinge is:

$T = F_1 d_1 + F_2 d_2 $

Being $F_1$ and $F_2$ the weights supported by each thread, and $d_1$ and $d_2$ the distances of each thread from the wall.

But we know that both weights are equal, because of simmetry ($F_1 = F_2 = F / 2$). And the middle point of the sign is $d_m = {d_1 + d_2 \over 2}$, so the equivalent weight there would be $F_m$ where:

$ T = F_m d_m $

And you get that $F_m$ equals the full weight of the sign.